# MySQL Select Statement, WHERE 'IN' Clause

Tags: php, sql, mysql, select

I currently have the following row in my table:

```
         course_data:
             user_id        days     <-- This is a varchar column.
               405          1,3,5
```

and I am trying to implement the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT usrID, usrFirst, usrLast, usrEmail
    FROM tblUsers
    WHERE usrID NOT IN
    (
        SELECT users.usrID
            FROM
                `course_data` courses,
                `tblUsers` users
            WHERE
                days IN ('$day')
    )
    GROUP BY usrID
    ORDER BY usrID
```

Basically, I want that row (with user 405) to be omitted if the $day variable includes a '1, 3, or 5'.

For example, if `$day = "1"`, it should return an empty query (because the number "1" is in the column "1,3,5").

However, I have not found this to be the case.  Even though `$day = "1"`, it still returns that row.

The only way that it won't return the row is if `$day= "1,3,5."`  Yet, I thought that the IN() clause would take any part of my variable and apply it to that column.

Any insights on what I'm doing wrong here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use [the `like` keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) to do a partial match of the char field:

```
where days like '%1%'
```

**Edit:**  VolkerK and Lukas Lalinsky both suggest MySQL's `find_in_set`, which is probably better than `like` for what you want to do.  However, the following recommendation about normalizing your database still applies.

**However,** you should not store multiple values in a single database field.  Instead, consider using two tables:

```
course_data:
    user_id

course_days:
    user_id
    day_number
```

Then, you would have the following data:

```
course_data:
    user_id
    405

course_days
    user_id    day_number
    405        1
    405        3
    405        5
```

You can then correctly query this schema.  For example:

```
select  cd.user_id
from    course_data as cd
where   cd.user_id not in
    (
        select  course_days.user_id
        from    course_days
        where   course_days.user_id = cd.user_id
            and course_days.day_number = 1
    )
```

(or, that should be close; I'm not *exactly* sure what you're trying to accomplish or what the rest of your schema looks like, so this is a best guess).

Comment: Thanks.  You're right about changing the structure.  I went ahead and did so.  Thank you.

Comment: "so this is a best guess": another (hopefully feasible) idea is to use a NOT EXISTS subquery as described at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html instead of `x NOT IN (subquery)`

Comment: %like% would give 11 for a search of 1, so it doesn't really suit, so this answer doesn't really apply to the original question. Answer from theomega seems more applicable to the OP.

Answer (score 13):

Remove the Quotes in the IN Statement. The Syntax is:

```
... WHERE column IN (1,2,3)
```

and not as you used it

```
... WHERE column IN ('1,2,3')
```

Also see the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) on IN, there are more examples.

Comment: Actually, sorry, I need some clarification.  I'm doing something wrong here.  If I use: WHERE days IN (1), it properly removes it and return an empty result.  But if I use: WHERE days IN (3), it does not return an empty query.  I would think that it should remove the query because '3' is in the query?  Any ideas?

Comment: I'd guess this is because it converts "1,3,5" into an int (stopping at the comma), and then sees that it matches.

Comment: Not sure why this isnt the accepted answer for the scenario given in the original post - although I accept that the accepted answer provides advice on correcting bad coding habits.

Answer (score 5):

I think the query you want is:

```
SELECT usrID, usrFirst, usrLast, usrEmail
FROM tblUsers
WHERE usrID NOT IN (
    SELECT user_id 
    FROM course_data
    WHERE find_in_set(?, days) > 0
)
ORDER BY usrID
```

But you should seriously consider normalizing the database, so that each day has it's own row.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you want the contents of the varchar field to be treated as a comma-separated list and test whether this list does not contain a certain value. For that you need the [find_in_set(str, strlist)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.
But keep in mind that MySQL can't use an index in that case and your query will always need a full table scan. It *might* be better not to store structured data (and run comparisons on the single elements) in a single column but to use another table and a JOIN as has been suggested in other responses.

Answer (score 0):

days does not hold a list of strings. It holds a single string. Is the string "1,3,5" inside one of the strings in {'1'}? Clearly the answer is no. Either refactor days into a different table, or be prepared to do more string manipulation